# Uniform cost search vs depth first search

Tags: algorithm

Is there any instance where a uniform cost search (dijkstra's algorithm) would return a greater-cost path than if using depth first search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-negative edge weighted graph, Dijkstra's algorithm will always find the shortest path. So it's impossible in non-negative weighted graph. However, in graph with negative edge weighted, Dijkstra's doesn't guarantee the shortest path, it maybe return a greater-cost path than DFS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Dijkstra should return the shortest path.